# iterate over arraylist and pass values to a whole table via jstl

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have an HTML table in my jsp page. This conains text fields and a drop down box.
From my servlet, I want to pass an arraylist of Strings called `myData`.

Therefore I attempt to use foreach to transfer the data to my html table:

```
<table border="1" >
  <c:forEach items="${myData}" var="result">
  <tr>
    <td><input name="from0" type="text" value="${result}"/></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
     <td>
    <select name="from8" id="from8" value="${result}">
       <option>Yes</option>
       <option>No</option>
    </select>
      </td>
  </tr>
  </c:forEach>
</table>
```

The arraylist is a simple arraylist of strings:

```
ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
//populate arraylist with values here

//forward the arraylist of strings
request.setAttribute("myData ", output);
request.getRequestDispatcher("Home.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Unfortunately the output generates multiple tables whose values all correspond to each element in my arraylist.

Comment: It is diffucuilt to guess the structure of your array list. It is possible to post the structure of yours?

Comment: @reporter i've edited the question, adding the arraylist structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on you given information, I tried to recover your situation. Honestly I couldn't do that. Here is my try for recovering:

```
<%
    ArrayList output = new ArrayList();
    output.add("Yes");
    output.add("No");
    request.setAttribute("myData", output);
%>
<table border="1">
  <c:set var="counterVar" value="0"/> //added because form field names and ids -in genral- must be unique.
  <c:forEach items="${myData}" var="result">
  <tr>
    <td><input name='from<c:out value="${counterVar}"/>_text' type="text" value='<c:out value="${result}"/>'></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
     <td>
    <select name='from<c:out value="${counterVar}"/>_select' id='from<c:out value="${counterVar}"/>' value='<c:out value="${result}"/>'>
       <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
       <option value="No">No</option>
    </select>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <c:set var="counterVar" value="${counterVar + 1}"/>
  </c:forEach>
</table>
```

This generates a good looking table. Can you provide an example link with your problem?